# How to read first 4 and last 4 bits from byte?

Tags: c#, byte, bit

C# how to read first 4 and last 4 bits from byte ?

Comment: Please post the code you have tried and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: i dont have any code, i just need to know how

Comment: Well, we _expect_ some effort here before a question is posted and for the question to show effort.

Answer (score 40):

Use bitwise `AND` and shifts, like this:

```
byte b = 0xAB;
var low = b & 0x0F;
var high = b >> 4;
```

Comment: Is it necessary to AND off the higher 4 bits after the shift down?

Comment: @MartinJames You are correct, `AND`ing off the rest is not necessary, because C# [does not sigh-extends bytes](http://ideone.com/GC0RKX). Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I would prefer simply using this -

```
byte a = 68;
byte high_bits = a>>4;
byte low_bits = a&15;
```

Answer (score 2):

In a convenient struct:

#### Usage

```
var hb = new HalvedByte(5, 10);
hb.Low -= 3;
hb.High += 3;
Console.Write(string.Format("{0} / {1}", hb.Low, hb.High));
// 2, 13
```

#### Code

```
public struct HalvedByte
{
    public byte Full { get; set; }

    public byte Low
    {
        get { return (byte)(Full & 0x0F); }

        set
        {
            if (value >= 16)
            {
                throw new ArithmeticException("Value must be between 0 and 16."); 
            }

            Full = (byte)((High << 4) | (value & 0x0F));
        }
    }

    public byte High
    {
        get { return (byte)(Full >> 4); }

        set
        {
            if (value >= 16)
            {
                throw new ArithmeticException("Value must be between 0 and 16.");
            }

            Full = (byte)((value << 4) | Low);
        }
    }

    public HalvedByte(byte full)
    {
        Full = full;
    }

    public HalvedByte(byte low, byte high)
    {
        if (low >= 16 || high >= 16)
        {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Values must be between 0 and 16.");
        }

        Full = (byte)((high << 4) | low);
    }
}
```

#### Bonus: Array (Untested)

If you ever need to use an array of these half bytes, this will simplify accessing:

```
public class HalvedByteArray
{
    public int Capacity { get; private set; }
    public HalvedByte[] Array { get; private set; }

    public byte this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= Capacity)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }

            var hb = Array[index / 2];

            return (index % 2 == 0) ? hb.Low : hb.High;
        }
        set
        {
            if (index < 0 || index >= Capacity)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }

            var hb = Array[index / 2];

            if (index % 2 == 0)
            {
                hb.Low = value;
            }
            else
            {
                hb.High = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public HalvedByteArray(int capacity)
    {
        if (capacity < 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Capacity must be positive.", "capacity");
        }

        Capacity = capacity;
        Array = new HalvedByte[capacity / 2];
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice and exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Simple method to do it.

Example use :

A: 10101110

B: 00001110

Get last 4 bits from A, so that output is like B

getBitRange(10101110, 0, 4);

```
//gets a bits from a byte, and return a byte of the new bits
byte getBitRange(byte data, int start, int _end){

//shift binary to starting point of range
byte shifted = (data >> start);

//calculate range length (+1 for 0 index)
int rangeLength = (_end-start)+1;

//get binary mask based on range length 
byte maskBinary;
 
switch (rangeLength){
case 1: maskBinary = 0b00000001; break;
case 2: maskBinary = 0b00000011; break;
case 3: maskBinary = 0b00000111; break;
case 4: maskBinary = 0b00001111; break;
case 5: maskBinary = 0b00011111; break;
case 6: maskBinary = 0b00111111; break;
case 7: maskBinary = 0b01111111; break;
case 8: maskBinary = 0b11111111; break;
default:
  // default statements
  Serial.println("Error: Range length too long!!");
}

//cancel out 
byte finalByte = (shifted & maskBinary);

return finalByte;
}
```

Comment: This code was written in C, but with minor tweaks it will work for C#